# Fiction Book Who Am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am a fiction character that follows these criteria:

> *A maiden huntress, whose life was brief*
>   *I left my brother with a lot of grief*
>   *Died fiddling with lots of gears*
>   *My friends, my friends, cast a lot of tears*

**HINT #1:**

> Chapter 3: [This character] Makes a Choice

Comment: Not a fictional character, but [Princess Diana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana,_Princess_of_Wales) fits. Diana was a maiden huntress; Princess Diana died young and was survived by her brother; the car whose crash killed her must have had gears; and there were a lot of tears at her massive funeral.

Comment: I had the exact same thought :-).

Comment: What’s spooky is that she died as a result of [_her driver fiddling with the gears while at those high speeds_](https://www.independent.ie/world-news/dianas-death-was-caused-by-error-over-gear-changes-26168919.html)

Comment: You said you'd post a hint containing a quote from that character! Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Artemis fowl (In the seventh book, "The Atlantis Complex")

A maiden huntress, whose life was brief

> in the ancient Greek religion and myth, **Artemis** is the goddess of the hunt, the wilderness, wild animals, the Moon, and chastity.

I left my brother with a lot of grief

> Colfer(The author) has said that he based Artemis on his younger brother Donal

Died fiddling with lots of gears

> In the seventh book, "The Atlantis Complex", Artemis contracts a mental disease called Atlantis Complex disease, similar to OCD,and has a strange fascination with bivouacking.   Artemis finds himself obsessed with the number 5 and fearing the number 4- (which in Chinese sounds like the word for death).

My friends, my friends, cast a lot of tears

> The disease worsens throughout the novel, leading to his distrust of his close friends.

Comment: Wasn't my original answer, but I think it works too! (If no one gets it in a couple days, I'll post the original answer.) You can try to figure it out!

Comment: I really don't think it does quite work, and I hope the intended answer fits more closely. I see the "maiden huntress" bit, but don't you think everything else here is a big stretch? (Not that I have anything better...)

Comment: Yeah, and the "life was brief" also is a bit stretchy. I'll give a hint. (It's a quote from the book the character appears in)

Comment: @TzuLi - Where's the hint?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - Can you see if my answer fits? I'm pretty sure I'm correct, but TzuLi appears to have been inactive for a while so I'm not gonna get that check. :(

Comment: It seems plausible but I'm not familiar with the books in question and so can't check details.

Answer (score 1):

The character is

> Bianca DiAngelo

A maiden huntress whose life was brief

> She joined the hunters of Artemis but died while saving the rest of the party at a very young age.

I left my brother with a lot of grief

> She left her brother Nico to go questing for Artemis when she was lost. She also made the tough decision to join the hunters.

Died fiddling with a lot of gears

> She was inside a giant metal monster and caused it to short-circuit which saved her friends.

Cast a lot of tears

> They were sad that she was gone.

And Hint 1 matches! :D