# Fiction Book Who Am I? #2

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Of course, I may be too early, but here it is:

> *When I promised not to tell*
> *I didn't know why not*
> *But when I came up with "freckles"*
> *I knew it had to stop*
>
> *I got caught by the talented*
> *And wore a sign that said*
> *That I was not to be trusted*
> *Oh no, oh no, not me!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably

> Marietta Edgecombe, a minor character in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* by J K Rowling.

This person

> joined "Dumbledore's Army", a group of students meeting in secret. They all signed a piece of parchment promising not to tell outsiders about it. Hermione Granger had (without telling anyone) enchanted it so that, as she put it, "if anybody’s run off and told Umbridge [...] it’ll make Eloise Midgen’s acne look like a couple of cute **freckles**". What it actually does to Ms Edgecombe, boils appear on her face spelling out the word SNEAK ("a sign that said / That I was not to be trusted") and she is unsurprisingly mortified.

Comment: BTW, if you liked this one, you can try [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83438/fiction-book-who-am-i).

Comment: I had a look at that one and haven't yet thought of a plausible answer.