# Fiction Book Who Am I? #3

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Previous ones: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83438/fiction-book-who-am-i) and [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/fiction-book-who-am-i-2).

> *I came with three but was entombed*
> *Smelled leaves for way too long*
> *I came out with the help of gold*
> *But see one missing*
>
> *Then I went west, almost sixteen*
> *With only days to spare*
> *I made a choice for my well-being*
> *And delayed it some years.*

Comment: Is the poem/riddle about the character in the book or the book itself? or would answer this question be considered too much of a hint?

Comment: @wolfsshield: It is the character. But you're right about the book. (or is that a spoiler?)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: Oops... I was away for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is inspired by @Invent Palooza's, though I think mine is more accurate

The character is

> Thalia Grace, from the Percy Jackson series.

I came with three but was entombed

> She arrived at Half-Blood Hill with Annabeth, Grover, and Luke

Smelled leaves for way too long

> Got turned into a tree

I came out with the help of gold

> Was brought back via the Golden Fleece

But see one missing

> But Luke had left them.

Then I went west, almost sixteen

> In the Titan's Curse, she traveled to San Francisco

With only days to spare

> She's days away from becoming 16

I made a choice for my well-being

> Became immortal

And delayed it some years.

> And forced the prophecy on Percy

Comment: Ah! I see where you got that from! Well done! +1

Comment: Yep! Just it's a tad bit wrong. No, not "There's always a time limit," remember the conversation with Apollo when they were at Westover?

Comment: Right, that's a better fit.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> *Percy Jackson and the Battle of the Labyrinth*

---

I came with three but was entombed...

> He came with Tyson, Grover, and Annabeth and was entombed (the Labyrinth)

Smelled leaves for way too long...

> Not sure about this one, yet. Maybe reference to search for Pan?

I came out with the help of gold/But see one missing...

> Not sure, either.

Then I went west, almost sixteen/With only days to spare/I made a choice for my well-being/And delayed it some years

> The Great Prophecy talks about a hero reaching sixteen against all odds. Percy is very close to reaching this age in *The Battle of the Labyrinth*